# Solution Technique for a Second Order PDE

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I am trying to solve a couple PDEs of the form $\cfrac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x \partial z}=p(x,y,z)f$, where $f=f(x,y,z)$. For one instance, $p(x,y,z)=\cfrac{x}{z}(\cfrac{a}{x}+\cfrac{b}{y})$.  If the $f$ on the r.h.s was a derivative I might know how to approach this, but as-is I am rather stuck.  Can anyone suggest a solution method?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The particular $p(x,y,z)$ you gave is separable in the $(x, y)$ and $z$ coordinates i.e it can be written as $p(x, y, z) = p_{1}(x, y) p_{2}(z)$ so the PDE is $$f_{xz} = p_{1}(x,y) p_{2}(z) f$$ If you search for a solution such that $f_{z} = p_{2}(z) f = z^{-1} f$ you find $f \propto z$. So let $f = z g(x, y)$ and substitution into the PDE yields $$g_{x} = p_{1}(x, y) g = (a + bx/y) g $$ and solving yields $$g = h(y) \exp(ax + bx^{2}/2y) \implies f = z h(y) \exp(ax + bx^{2}/2y)$$ with $h$ arbitrary i.e we essentially assumed $f = g_{1}(x,y) g_{2}(z)$.

Comment: Thank you very much M.C., that was very educational.